# Clone succeeded, but checkout failed because invalid path

Tags: github

I am trying to clone a Github repository, but keep getting this error. 
[image]

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Please post the image as text, that is easier to find in the future (SO search etc)

Comment: I am on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:` is an invalid character on some filesystems. Windows, for example.

Simplest fix is to check out the repo on a filesystem which supports `:`, Mac or Linux, and rename the file.